# python multi processing with shared memory and pytorch data loader - RuntimeError:use CUDA with multiprocessing you must use the 'spawn' start method

Tags: memory, pytorch, multiprocessing, shared

I am trying to implement a program with a producer and a consumer classes. The producer class reads the numpy array(an image) and puts it in a shared memory and the consumer class will read the numpy array data from the shared memory and apply a pytorch inference model on that.

Below is the shared memory creation code snippet.

```
 import multiprocessing as multi_processing
 def create_shared_memory(self):
     type_code = "I"
     size = int(np.prod(self.image_frame_shape))
     frame_lock = multi_processing.Lock()
        
     shared_memory_array = multi_processing.Array(typecode_or_type = type_code, size_or_initializer = size, lock = frame_lock)
     buffered_array = np.frombuffer(shared_memory_array.get_obj(), dtype = type_code).reshape(self.image_frame_shape)

     shared_memory_object_tuple = (shared_memory_array, buffered_array)
     return shared_memory_object_tuple
```

I have created a pytorch data loader with the below code snippet.

```
inference_data_loader = create_loader(
            InferCustomDataset(
                frame_list,
                self.validation_transforms,
                input_size = self.model_params['input_size'][1:]
            ),
            **self.model_params
        )
```

And the `InferCustomDataset` class is as below.

```
class InferCustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, imlist,  custom_transforms = None, input_size = (224, 224)):
        self._imlist = imlist
        self.transform = custom_transforms
        self.input_size = input_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img = Image.fromarray(self._imlist[idx]).convert('RGB')
        img = img.resize(self.input_size)

        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
        return img, torch.tensor(-1, dtype=torch.long)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._imlist)
```

When i try to iterate through the `data loader`, i am getting the below error/exception.

`For loop` : `for image_data, _ in inference_data_loader:`

```
Process ConsumerVHP-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/mvi/modules/vac/src/consumer_video_handler_process.py", line 183, in run
    classes = self.infer_on_frame_list(buffered_images_list)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mvi/modules/vac/src/consumer_video_handler_process.py", line 92, in infer_on_frame_list
    for image_data, _ in inference_data_loader:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 363, in __iter__
    self._iterator = self._get_iterator()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 314, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 939, in __init__
    torch.cuda.current_device(),
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 481, in current_device
    _lazy_init()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 206, in _lazy_init
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
Exception ignored in: <function _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter.__del__ at 0x7f990c904a60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1358, in __del__
    self._shutdown_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1317, in _shutdown_workers
    self._mark_worker_as_unavailable(worker_id, shutdown=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1258, in _mark_worker_as_unavailable
    assert self._workers_status[worker_id] or (self._persistent_workers and shutdown)
AttributeError: '_MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter' object has no attribute '_workers_status'

^CProcess PproducerVHProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/mvi/modules/vac/src/main.py", line 195, in <module>
    producer_reader_process.join()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 43, in wait
Traceback (most recent call last):
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/mvi/modules/vac/src/producer_video_handler_process.py", line 48, in run
    ret = shared_memory_array.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It is throwing the `RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method` error.

In my `main` program, if i use, `set_start_method('spawn')`, the consumer code is just getting the numpy array with all zeros and looks like consumer process is not getting the image (numpy array) from the shared memory.

I also tried by setting `"num_workers": 0`, but getting the below error.

```
ValueError: persistent_workers option needs num_workers > 0
```

Could you let me know how to get the numpy array (image) that was sent to shared memory by the producer and apply the pytorch inference in the consumer process.

I also tried `torch.multiprocessing` module instead of python's `multiprocessing` module, but that also resulted in the same error.

```
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
```

Appreciate your suggestion/help on how to fix this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The following change fixed this issue.

In my `if __name__ == '__main__'`, i was calling the `create_shared_memory()` method.

```
shared_mem_handler = SharedMemoryHandler()
shared_memory_object_tuple = shared_mem_handler.create_shared_memory()
```

I moved this code outside of this `main` method, and added just under my `import` statements. This helped to fix this.